# How can i overload a function at run time in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

rt. 
I want to redefine a function at run time so that i can change the behavior of the system at run time.
thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eli. If i write (set! foo (lambda (x) ...different stuff...)) in a file then i can just require that file, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- if you're using racket, then you need the setting to be done in the same module.  (he comment should be next to the answer, btw...)

Answer (score 5):

```
(define (foo x) ...stuff...)
(set! foo (lambda (x) ...different stuff...))
```

Comment: Eli, Set! works. but only for the function which i define after that.

What i really want is that. I have a function A which use another function B.
In runtime i want to redefine B to different behavior. So that A also get a new behavior. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.  Again, if you're using Racket, then the `set!` should be in the same module -- for example, you can define a `set-foo` function that will do the mutation.  Alternatively, you can use a parameter instead -- that's the more common way to encapsulate such global state.

Answer (score 1):

It might be advisable to use let to do this locally, this can also apply to keywords in this sense:

```
(let ((define +))
   (define 2 3)) ; ===> 5
```

Or even redefine them to constants, remember, Scheme is a lisp-1:

```
(let ((define 2) (+ 4))
   (- define +)) ; ===> -2
```

Or even:

```
(let ((quote /))
   '3) ===> 1/3
```

Doing it only locally preserves the functional style.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to overload a function you defined earlier, simply define it again. This also works for redefining functions such as car and cdr, e.g. to make car into cdr:

> (define (car x) (cdr x))

However, I think you won't be able to affect *other* already defined functions with such a redefinition, so a system function which uses car will still use the original system car and not yours:

> (define (test x) (car x))
>
> (define (car x) (cdr x))
>
> (test '(1 2 3))

1

I guess the reason for this is that internally the symbols disappear once a function gets read or evaluated and the symbols are replaced by what they're bound to; in this case, the actual code of the function. So rebinding a symbol to a different function won't affect the rest of your already defined code. This is usually a good thing because it helps uphold referential transparency.

If you want to redefine scheme keywords such as lambda or cond, use let-syntax (see http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language)

Comment: Using `define` a second time is bad habit, and the fact that the above returns 1 is due to related reasons.

Comment: Bad habit: okay. But as to the "related reasons": I don't think so. (test '(1 2 3)) also returns 1 and not (2 3) when you redefine car using the (set! ... ) syntax, and as I said, I think this makes perfect sense when you think about how binding works. Agreed?

Comment: Sorry, disregard my last comment and my answer. Seems I was using a non-standard scheme implementation to test this. MIT scheme works as you say, which makes my answer wrong.

Comment: Even a single implementation can produce different results based on actual settings that are used.  For example, you're seeing a result of inlining values for known primitives (`car`), which can be disabled.